# lowriter works only with sudo

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo

When I run (as www-data user):

```
lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir ".../pdf" ".../pdf/file.doc"
```

I got error: **Error: Please reverify input parameters...** and file is not converted.

But when I add sudo:

```
sudo lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir ".../pdf" ".../pdf/file.doc"
```

file is converted without errors.

Is there a way, how to find out, what libraries or programs lowriter uses and add permission for www-data user as well?
Thanks

Comment: are you sure in both the cases same lowriter binary is executed? Just check `which lowriter` and `sudo which lowriter`

Comment: Are you sure it's not a permissions issue with the directory you're trying to write the converted file to?

Comment: @SagarSakre $ which lowriter: /usr/bin/lowriter

$ sudo which lowriter: /usr/bin/lowriter

Comment: @arco444 /pdf $ ls -la: drwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     0 Oct  9 11:33 .

Answer (score 0):

The problem was www-data user does't have a home dir, which lowriter uses.